# Want setup button outside my settings

Tags: setup

I want to move set up button outside the mysettings. Want to access it directly on the home page, instead of going to the mysettings.
See attached screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have the **Global Header** turned on, which is causing this behavior. You could turn it off by going to your Profile, go to System Permissions, and uncheck the View Global Header checkbox.

[image: Global Header]

Answer (score 2):

If you enabled the `New User Interface Theme` under `Build -> Customize -> User Interface`, you will be getting the Setup as a Link near to your name instead of an option pops out when you click your Name.